# How to Get The Higher Value in an Option Group?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a relatively simple question, but unfortunately I couldn't find it out ...

so I have a form with multiple option groups, ranging from two to five options per group.
I need to use an IF Statement to check if all the option groups in the form have the higher value selected, to do something else in the form.

So my question is how to loop through all the options groups to find whether the user have selected the higher value in all of them or not.
I know how to loop all of them

```
Private Sub HValues()
    Dim opg As Control
        For Each opg In Me.Controls
            If optionsg.value = ?????? Then 'this is the function I need
             do something
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I need the function or method that well get me the highr value in each option group.

Comment: What would be the sum of the highest values? If the sum of selected does not equal sum of highest then not all have the highest selected. Do you need to do something based on this sum value or do you need to do something for each option group based on value selected?

Comment: Nothing about the sum at all. I need to check that the value of the selected option is the higher value (3 in a 3-options group , or 5 in 5-options group ...ect), and I need it to loop all the option groups in that form with the same way..... and if it returns True, I will do something else ...

Comment: You want to loop through options of one group, determine if max option selected and do something, repeat process with each group? If you want to determine if ALL options have max selected before determining an action, then my suggestion to sum is an option. This does require knowing the sum value of max options and hard coding that limit in expression. So far, I cannot find syntax for looping option controls within a group. This expression could possibly return max value for a group: `(Me.Opt1.Controls.Count - 1) / 2`.